# How to get the tier pricing option for an Custom Option?

Tags: custom-options, tierprice, tiered-pricing

How can I get the tier pricing to apply to Custom Options within the products in Magento 1.9?

Currently it is a fixed price or percentage.

Struggling to find any concrete advice or plugins that will allow me to do so.